# Peltier Power supply problem

Tags: power-supply, short-circuit, peltier

I am doing a project using a peltier TEC1-12706, however I am stuck on powering up the device. I am using a computer adapter power supply(20V;90W) and I it coupled with a synchronous buck-boost module to bring it down to 12V. During the initial seconds the power supply did handle powering up the module but later smoke came out with my buck-boost converter.

1. What are your recommendations for the powersupply? BTW, the peltier supply was also coupled with computer cooler which consumes around 500mA and a raspi fan on the other side.
2. Follow-up question, is the peltier usually reads as short using DMM
   buzz test? Ohmmeter around 1ohm only. Sorry, this is my first time working with the component.

Comment: Please provide a datasheet for the peltier and your supply module; it's a 6A device so not exactly a small load at 72W. You need to consider conversion losses and oftten the supply `watts' are… well, fake. Also, it's normal that it measures as a short since it's essentially *two welded wires*

Comment: @LorenzoMarcantonio Thanks for the answer. I thought I messed up the module that is why it always buzzing. I currently don't have a datasheet or manufacturer p/n of the peltier which I bought online. I was hoping most mfg have almost same specs for same TEC1-12706. I have tried my to drive my project with a var powersupply but it switches to CC. I am hoping this is only a low supply issue.

Comment: 1 Ohm sound a bit too low for my taste. Do you have a proper heatsink on the hot end? TECs die pretty fast when they are operated without heatsink.

Comment: Why do you need 12Vdc which will draw about ~5A [link](https://peltiermodules.com/peltier.datasheet/TEC1-12706.pdf), can you explain your application better? I'd recommend going with lower voltage if possible like 5Vdc and using dedicated external power supply